# Is it possible to pass a pointer-to-class-member as an single argument in C++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, function-pointers

Here is well described how to call member function by pointer:
http://www.newty.de/fpt/functor.html

But the functor needs to get 2 arguments: pointer-to-object and pointer-to-member-function:

```
TSpecificFunctor(TClass* _pt2Object, void(TClass::*_fpt)(const char*))
{ pt2Object = _pt2Object;  fpt=_fpt; }
```

call:

```
(*pt2Object.*fpt)(string);
```

Is it possible to pass single argument like C-style:

```
func() -- call
func -- function pointer
```

Why **obj.method** isn't complete pointer-to-class-member?

Comment: Can you clarify the statement "Why obj.method isn't complete pointer-to-class-member?" what does it mean?

Comment: `(*pt2Object.*fpt)(string);` won't work. You need `(pt2Object->*fpt)(string);`.

Comment: Naveen, I want to get single argument which points to particular object (obj) and particular class-member (member). But it seems I'm starting to understand.... Polymorphism does not give the potential ability to do what I want..

Comment: Potatoswatter, Why? *pt2Object is a dereferenced pointer which can access to members using '.', isn't it?

Comment: Postfix `.*` binds before prefix `*`. You would have to do `((*pt2Object).*fpt)(string);`.

Comment: "Why `obj.method` isn't complete pointer-to-class-member?" I don't think there's any particular reason why it couldn't be. Currently it isn't a legal expression, so in theory a meaning for it could be added to the language. Next version of the language might be 5-10 years or so, so get your feature requests in now via your national standards body!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `object.*ptmf` doesn't create an intermediate object. It has no meaning and is forbidden by the language. You *have* to immediately call the result of accessing a pointer to member function.

You can explicitly create such an object using `std::bind`, which interprets the ptmf as a functor object, and makes the implicit `this` argument explicit.

```
auto fn = std::bind( ptmf, object, std::placeholders::_1 );
std::function< void( const char * ) > stdfn = fn;
fn( "foo" ); // equivalent to object.*ptmf( "foo" );
```

http://ideone.com/ds24F

Note that this functionality is new in C++11. Although C++03 TR1 has `function` and `bind`, they won't perform this conversion on a ptmf. (Plain C++03 can do the job with `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind1st`, but they are extremely painful to use and have been deprecated.)

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, he wants to pass that to a function as an argument, therefore you would need to specify the type - not use auto

Comment: @BЈовић already updated as such ;v) . Note that there is no way to explicitly specify the return type of `std::bind` and `std::function` is likely to add an indirect call, so `auto` is preferable unless you need to store it outside local scope or pass to a non-template function.

Comment: @SteveJessop Likewise, already updated :) just refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pass a pointer-to-class-member as an single argument in C++?

No, it is not possible. You need the object of the class on which you want to call the method.

You can go around this by using [lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions), like in next example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void call( const std::function< void( const char * a ) > & fn )
{
  fn("hi");
}

void foo( const char * a )
{
  std::cout << "foo : " << a << std::endl;
}

class bar
{
public:
  void operator()( const char * a )
  {
    std::cout << "bar : " << a << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  bar b;
  const auto f1 = [&]( const char * a ){ b(a); };

  const auto f2 = foo;

  call( f1 );
  call( f2 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself if it is possible to call member method without specifying an object.
Consider this:

```
class A {
public: void m() {}
};
int main() {
   m(); // can't call without object - like: A a; a.m(); 
}
```

Comment: I wrote the wrong comment and erased it, sorry. A.m is delirium :) If you creates an object, A obj, why obj.m is not a correct pointer-to-member?

Comment: @legotron  `A::m()` is defined only once for every object in class A and derived.  It is is equivalent to "C" function `A_m(A* const this)`. Similar question: having function `int f(int i);` would you expect to have valid address to `&f(1)`? You can only take `pf = &f` and use it as `(*pf)(1)` - you cannot say `pf = &f(1); (*pf)()`